# MVC Linq using GroupBy Min Max and returning view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a table and need to GroupBy a date tBooked
I need the group to return the Min StartDate and the Max EndDate
I need the sum of days.
I have written the following:

```
        var model = _db.AnnualLeaves.Where(r => r.StafferId == stafferId)
                    .GroupBy(r => r.tBooked)
                    .Select(m => new
                    {
                        start = m.Min(r => r.StartDate),
                        end = m.Max(r => r.EndDate),
                        daycount = m.Sum(r => r.Days)
                    });
```

I cannot seem to get the model to return in the view. I have tried all kinds of foreach but nothing has I keep getting errors.

If I create the View with the following:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewData.Model)
{
@item
}
```

The view renders:

```
{ start = 15/10/2014 00:00:00, end = 21/10/2014 00:00:00, daycount = 5 }

{ start = 28/06/2015 00:00:00, end = 03/07/2015 00:00:00, daycount = 4.5 }
```

Buy I am unable to get `@item.start` onto the page.

I have tried creating a model and change the above `var model` to `IEnumerable` against the model below.

```
public class ListLeaveModel 
{
public DateTime start { get; set; }
public DateTime end { get; set; }
public double daycount { get; set; }
}
```

I just appear to be going around in circles now. I have only just started with MVC and C# so it is probably something very simple! I hope that is clear - I have no idea what is important.

Comment: Have you tried returning the data itself, i.e. not using ViewData / ViewBag... return this.View(model); If that doesn't solve it; I suspect you are returning an IQueryable, so on your linq statement try putting a ToList() at the end.

Comment: Try `@String.Format("{0:d}", item.start)`

Comment: Thanks guys. 
Paul, yes, I tried all of that - when I added .ToList() to the end it went a caused another problem. Fixed as below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not return anymouse type

```
var model = _db.AnnualLeaves.Where(r => r.StafferId == stafferId)
                    .GroupBy(r => r.tBooked)
                    .Select(m => new ListLeaveModel 
                    {
                        start = m.Min(r => r.StartDate),
                        end = m.Max(r => r.EndDate),
                        daycount = m.Sum(r => r.Days)
                    });
   return View(model.ToList());
```

for your View:

```
@model IList<ListLeaveModel>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   @item.start
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Not sure if it is a given, but I got an error... but I just needed to add the full namespace @ model IList<HolidaysDev.Models.ListLeaveModel> Really appreciate the help... not sure I would have ever got there.